# How to calculate rows in html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time

I want to calculate the time in rows. In the below code only first row is showing total and overtime. but I want to see all the rows doing the same.

Html:

```
<table border=1>
<tr><th>Time In</th><th>Time Out</th><th>Lunch</th><th>After Lunch Time in</th><th>After Lunch Time out</th><th>Total Hours</th><th>Overtime</th> </tr>
<tr><td><input type="time" id="start" name="logintime"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
<td><input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
<td><input id="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="time" id="start" name="logintime"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
<td><input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
<td><input id="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="time" id="start" name="logintime"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
<td><input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
<td><input id="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="time" id="start" name="logintime"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
<td><input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
<td><input id="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="time" id="start" name="logintime"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
<td><input type="time" id="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
<td><input type="time" id="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
<td><input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
<td><input id="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $time1 = $("#start");
var $time2 = $("#end");
var $time3 = $("#lunch");
var $time4 = $("#startafterlunch");
var $time5 = $("#endafterlunch");
var $diff = $("#totalTime");
var $over = $("#overTime");

function updateHours(){   

    var dtStart = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time1.val());
    var dtEnd = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time2.val());
    var dtLunch= new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time3.val());
    var dtStartafterlunch = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time4.val());
    var dtEndafterlunch = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time5.val());

    var diff = ((dtEnd - dtStart)+(dtEndafterlunch-dtStartafterlunch)) / 1000;

    var totalTime = 0;
    var overTime = 0;

    if (diff > 60*60*8) {

        overTime = formatDate(diff - 60*60*8);
    } else {
        totalTime = formatDate(diff);
    }
    totalTime = formatDate(diff);
    $diff.val(totalTime);
    $over.val(overTime);
}

function formatDate(diff){
    var hours = parseInt( diff / 3600 ) % 24;
    var minutes = parseInt( diff / 60 ) % 60;
    var seconds = diff % 60;

    return (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
}

$("#start, #end, #lunch, #startafterlunch, #endafterlunch, #totalTime").on("change, keyup", function(){
    if($time1.val() && $time2.val() && $time4.val() && $time5.val()){
        updateHours();
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dpk11/9f66wef7/

please help...
thanks!

Comment: What is happening in your fiddle?  Explain what is happening and what u want to achieve ?

Comment: @MayurPatel when u enter first five fields in first row as 07:00 12:00 12:00 13:00 17:50
u'll see the total and overtime. but when u enter the same for second and other rows it wont do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't used `id` attribute. The `id` attribute should be used only for unique element in the page. When using the `$('#...')` selector, jQuery will always return one element, even if there is several corresponding elements in the page.

Moreover, the `updateHours` method should take in parameter the row of the modified input, so it can recover the input values, and compute total times :

```
function updateHours(row){   
    var $time1 = row.find('[name="logintime"]');
    var $time2 = row.find('[name="logouttime"]');
    var $time3 = row.find('[name="lunch"]');
    var $time4 = row.find('[name="afterlunchlogin"]');
    var $time5 = row.find('[name="afterlunchlogout"]');
    var $diff = row.find('.totalTime');
    var $over = row.find('.overTime');

    ...
}
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9f66wef7/2/

Comment: I'm Sorry to bother you but this not working in my browser... can you please tell me why is that?

Comment: Which browser do you use ?

Comment: I think the problem is with dateInput... Instead of using "7/20/2015 " I was using dateInput... as this example jsfiddle.net/orazem/hf1ckkLe/2 it works fine if I'm using "7/20/2015 " in place of dateInput.

Comment: What do you mean by "dateInput" ? I try using a input of "date" type, and it's working too :  http://jsfiddle.net/hf1ckkLe/3/

Comment: please check here http://jsfiddle.net/dpk11/hes6pkbj/2/ ... its working in jsfiddle  but its not working through netbeans... please tellme know where i'm going wrong?

Comment: I executed the same code in a local file on my computer, and it's working correctly. Are you using exactly the same code ? Try to look in the debugger tool of google chrome (F12) if an error is present in your page (in the console tab).

Comment: I dont know what I was doing wrong before... but now its working thanks  a lot.

Comment: i might be bothering you by asking the same question again and again... but i have to do according to the data i'm changing... so can you please tell me if i want to give different name's for all the fields like for logindate1 logindate2... until logindate5 same similarly for other fields. how must i calculate...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Could you explain more ?

Comment: Please check name values of input fields in the html code
http://jsfiddle.net/dpk11/hes6pkbj/5/

Comment: OK. Given that the "name" does not identify your fields (different for each field), you need to select your field using an other attribute (the "class" for example) : http://jsfiddle.net/hes6pkbj/7/ . Be careful, you still use the "id" attribute for date fields. Reminder : the "id" attribute must be unique in a page and be used for identify a unique element. The "class" attribute is used to identify several element which have a common point. The "name" attribute is used to define the name of the property sent at submit.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was a great help

Comment: My application is working fine in google chrome. but its not working in internet explorer. do you know why is that?

Comment: What's the version of internet explorer  ?

Comment: thank you for replying... E10... I'm trying to run the application.... it is trying to open or save the index.jsp page.

Comment: If you use the same input that in the jsfiddle (input type date), this will not work with older browser (which are not supporting HTML5). If this is not the problem, I will need more information : The code which not working, eventually the errors present in the IE debugger, etc. Perhaps you can open a new post for that.

Comment: yes... I'm using the same code which is in the jsfiddle.

Comment: And your problem is that the date fields are just text fields ? You can use datepicker widget, to make it works with older browser. Ex : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/, https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any sort of marker to differentiate between rows.  You have 5 different rows, but each of the inputs has the same ID as the comparable input in the last row.  When you're selecting and ID, Jquery only cares about the first one it finds.  My advice would be to add a keyup event listener to the inputs, then fire a function that loops through each TR element and calculates the values of the child inputs.

Comment: thanks for the reply... Can you please give me an example of it, as I'm not familiar with jquery.

Comment: @dpk I can give you a good start

    $("tr").each(function(){
        var startTime = $(this).children("#start");
        // repeat for each id
        // do your math with each variable
        $(this).children("#overtime").value(calculatedOvertime);
    }

The calculatedOvertime would be the total that your math function calculates